# Salesforce Lightning Workspace API

Tags: salesforce, workspace, lwc

I am using lightning workspace api
I am not utilising their wire function for e.g. getEnclosingTabId()
I am only using focus sub tab and getFocusedTabInfo

Now I need enclosing tab id, I can't use this wire as in our org lighting web security is disabled and we can't enable it

What suggestion do you suggest
Should I shift my code to aura or any other suggestion.

I have tried getFocusedTabInfo but it isn't giving the expected result`your text`